# How to make the bounding box adapt to fit new parameters?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

folks.

I've updated to the new version of Illustrator CC a few months back, and have only now needed to work with triangles. I've noticed, however, after rounding the corners of the triangle (thus shrinking its dimensions) the bounding box doesn't change to match the new dimensions. This makes things like rotating around a centre point and transformations inaccurate.

Before:
[image: triangle with points]
After:
[image: triangle with rounded corners]
Reset bounding box is greyed out.
Any ideas?

EDIT: Here's a picture of the path and points after I've rounded the corners.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illustrator CC 2017 reset bounding box missing on square](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82986/illustrator-cc-2017-reset-bounding-box-missing-on-square)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are using  Effect > Stylize > Round Corners
What is happening is the original path data and points are still being held onto. In order to get rid of it you need to expand the arrearance.
Object > Expand Appearance
[image]

Comment: Expanding will work but with the loss of edit ability. Rotate, then round then expand, if that is possible.

Comment: Nope, using live corners. It adjusts the nodes and the path. Expanding was the first thing I tried.

Comment: As long as you are using live corners on a filled shape the corners are going to stay live, so you cant reset the bounding box.

Comment: can I ask why you need the bounding box resized?

Answer (score 0):

Clearly an issue with the bounding box and live corners.

I have no solution - I think only Adobe can address this since it appears to be a drawing issue with live shape bounds and the Bounding box. Expanding appears to be the only way to correct what the Bounding Box sees as the "bounds".

However, why do you even need the Bounding Box???

The Bounding box is *worthless* for everything other than resizing area text frames. The **only** unique thing the Bounding Box will do is resize an area text box without transforming the text within it. That's it. There's nothing else the Bounding Box does that can't be done in other, just as easy, ways.

Turn **off** the Bounding Box (View  > Hide Bounding Box). This is the **first** thing I do when I launch Illustrator after installing it.

If you need handles to scale/rotate etc, tap the **E** key and use the **Free Transform** tool... same basic thing with additional benefits and it doesn't suffer from this bounding error.

[image]

The Bounding Box was only ever added to Illustrator (CS4 by the way) to make CorelDraw users feel more comfortable when they switched. It never existed prior to that and wasn't needed. And Adobe hasn't added *any* new features to it since it's introduction. The Bounding Box, as a whole, is an unnecessary feature.

Answer (score -1):

Click **Edit > Preferences > General** (<kbd>Ctrl/Commadn</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) and untick *Use Preview Bounds*

Comment: This won't work to achieve what they want.